# Update SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am writting a SQL query , where I need to update the colouns in dummy coloumn  with the value on the basis of  same `post_id` such that for `post_id '1'` all the rows will have `'abc'` in there dummy coloumn.

Similarly for the `post_id '2'` all the rows will have `'def'` in the coloumn under dummy .

```
post_id |meta_key|dummy
1         url      abc
1         link     Null
1         key      Null
1         data     Null
2         url      def
2         link     Null
2         key      Null
2         data     Null
```

The query I tried is :

```
update <table_name>
  set dummy = ( select meta_value 
                       from <table_name> 
                       where meta_key = 'url' 
                       AND post_id = '1'
               ) 
  where post_id IN ('1') ;
```

This is working , but i want a dynamic query as i cant hardcode the `post_id` value as the data is like 10,000 post_ids.

The data after updating will look like this

```
post_id|meta_key|dummy
1        url      abc
1        link     abc
1        key      abc
1        data     abc
2        url      def
2        link     def
2        key      def
2        data     def
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update Table_Name 
set dummy = Case when post_id='1' then 'abc'
                 when post_id='2' then 'def'
end
where post_id in('1','2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
SET dummy = CASE post_id 
WHEN 1 THEN 'abc'
WHEN 2 THEN 'def'
END
WHERE post_id IN(1,2)
```

Due to the comment that posted , I am giving a sample code how to use this

If you have the "post_id" and corresponding "dummy" value in an array named "value". It is javascript code since I am using the node.js.

```
for(var key in values){
dummypart += ' WHEN '+values[key]['post_id']+' THEN '+values[key]['dummy'];
ids+= ','+ values[key]['post_id'];
}
```

And I generate the query as

```
var query = 'UPDATE <table_name> SET dummy = CASE post_id '+dummypart+'END 
WHERE post_id IN('+ids+')';
```

The exact query will be now

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
    SET dummy = CASE post_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'abc'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'def'
    END
    WHERE post_id IN(1,2)
```

If the value array contains ids 1 and 2 ; and corresponding values.
So **in a single query I able to update multiple rows in a table**. **I do't know your exact requirement**. But since you are trying to generate dynamic query, try this.

Comment: A CASE with 10000 different post_id:s?

Comment: I cant hardcode the values , as i have post_id more than 10,000 .

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Lindbäck Read question. He mentioned "dynamic query".

Comment: No. You need to generate query in your application logic. I implemented this for updating hundreds of entries in a table with single query. I cannot use 100 queries to update the entries.It is one solution for this. –

Comment: @Damodaran I have read the question. Generating an UPDATE that contains a CASE with around 10000 WHEN clauses doesn't sound like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check that each post_id really only has one value, so you don't end up doing an update based on a randomly selected value of several available:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(DISTINCT dummy) dummyCount
FROM TABLE
WHERE dummy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dummy) > 1
```

If that has results, you should check them.

Then if there really is just one non-null dummy value per each post_id, you can update all the nulls as described in the OP like so:

```
UPDATE T
SET dummy = SRC.dummy
FROM TABLE T
JOIN 
   (SELECT post_id, dummy
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE dummy IS NOT NULL) SRC ON SRC.post_id = T.post_id
--WHERE dummy IS NOT NULL > should not be used
WHERE dummy IS NULL
```